# iOS Build one View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building an app(swift iOS9) that requires login and of course it has multiple views after login. Is there a way to only build and run one view that is after the login so that I don't have to enter login information every time?

thanks..

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're asking how to show different view controllers at launch (ie. login the first time, some other view subsequently). Something along the lines of the following in your AppDelegate (untested code):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let firstVC = (shouldLogin) ? "LoginVC" : "OtherVC"
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(firstVC)
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() 
    return true
}
```

Then `NSUSerDefaults` is commonly used to store the fact they're logged in, which you can read and set "shouldLogin" appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, open up your storyboard file, select the view you want to start the application in, and in the inspector view check the `is initial view controller` as shown here:

[image: Setting initial view controller]

Also remember that if you bypass the login you need to check your app's logic to mock the user login state so it'll work as it should, and more important remember to revert the initial view controller to the start one once you're done.

Image is from [this blog post](http://www.timdietrich.me/blog/swift-multiple-storyboards/)

Comment: what if your not using storyboard and programming the views?

Comment: Well you'll need to show some code first then.
But you would simply load the next view instead of the view that shows the login.

Comment: got it, just had to set the view to my rootViewController

Comment: great, I wouldn't recommend working without a storyboard though, your work will get much more complex over time. learn to use the storyboard and make your life easier :)